# How can I create a christmas tree with while?

Tags: python

I am currently working on some code, a student on quarantine and I am trying to solve a problem with a christmas tree but can't quite get into it.

The christmas tree has to be done with "while", I have tried but I only get half the tree.

Line of code:

```
lines=1
maxlines=9
while lines>=maxlines:
  print (lines*'*')
  lines+=1
```

What I am  getting:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
```

What I want to get:

```
         *
        ***
       *****
      *******
     *********
    ***********
   *************
  ***************
 *****************
*******************
```

Comment: What is supposed to be `the rest of that tree`?

Comment: Edited what I want to get, something like this.

Comment: The desired output has spaces before the stars - have you tried putting any spaces into what you're `print`-ing, before the stars?

Comment: No, not really... I can't seem to figure it out, I haven't worked on while at all. I am still a starter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, your code cannot work since in your while loop the `lines` are never greater than the `maxlines` so the statement is `False`.

As mentioned by all the other people, you are missing spaces. Another way as close as possible to your code is this:

```py
lines=1
maxlines=9

while lines<=maxlines:
    # print the leading spaces, the left part and the right side of the tree
    print((maxlines-lines)*' '+ lines*'*'+(lines-1)*'*')
    lines+=1
```

which gives:

```
        *
       ***
      *****
     *******
    *********
   ***********
  *************
 ***************
*****************
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. This will print the tree

```
def tree(n):

    # total spaces
    k = 2 * n - 2

    # number of rows
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        j = 0

        # inner loop for number spaces
        while j < k:
            print(end=" ")
            j = j + 1

        # decrementing k after loop
        k = k - 1

        # number of columns
        j = 0
        while j < i + 1:
            print("* ", end="")
            j = j + 1

        # end line
        print("\r")
        i = i + 1


# Begining
n = 5
tree(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
star = 1 # Star count
maxLines = 9 # Total number of lines
actualLines = 0 # Lines count

while actualLines <= maxLines:

     # print the necessary spaces before the stars   print the stars
     print(str(abs(maxLines - actualLines ) * ' ') + str(star * '*'))

     star += 2 # add 2 stars every new line
     actualLines += 1 # add 1 to the line counting
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer. Feel free to ask any question about the code above.

Comment: Done! Thanks once again.